# Rest Assured - Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type

Tags: java, restful-authentication, rest-assured

I am using **Rest** Assured for testing **API**

WHEN I post a request for **authentication**, the error occurs to say that: `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"`

Here is my test method

```
 @Test
public void authenticate()
{
    AuthenDto authenDto = new AuthenDto("username","password","false","Login");
    given()
            .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
            .accept("application/json, text/plain, */*")
            .body(authenDto)
    .when()
            .post("ENDPOINT")
    .then()
            .statusCode(200);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and resolved the issue by using **formParams** in place of **body**. Code snippet below:

```
given().
contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").
accept("*/*").
formParams(bodyContent).relaxedHTTPSValidation(). //bodyContent=hashMap variable
when().
post("/register").
then().
extract().
response();
```

Credit to following post: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/841

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but did you try without the "charset"? Like this:

```
.contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Or

```
.contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
```

Comment: There is no suggestion for APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED in ContentType at all

Comment: There is, if  you're importing "org.apache.http.entity.ContentType"

Comment: it isnt compatible with Rest Assured

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. For Rest assuerd it should be "ContentType.URLENC", but I don't know if that helps. As I don't know what parameters you're exactly sending in the body, I can't really test it myself.

Comment: This doesnot work , still getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded